# Handle check/uncheck multiple checkboxes - React

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, foreach

[image]

```
    getEmailUserRows() {
    let emailRows = this.props.emailRows
    let emailTemplate = emailRows.map((row) => {
        return (
            <tr key={row.email}>
                <td height="70">
                    <span class="txt-limit">
                        <small>{row.email}</small>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                            id="sttng1"
                            name="sttng1"
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={row.emailCategoryList.transactionalEmails}/>
                        <label for="sttng1"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                            id="sttng2"
                            name="sttng2"
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={row.emailCategoryList.settlementEmails}/>
                        <label for="sttng2"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                            id="sttng3"
                            name="sttng3"
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={row.emailCategoryList.crmEmails}/>
                        <label for="sttng3"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                            id="sttng4"
                            name="sttng4"
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={row.emailCategoryList.onboardingEmails}/>
                        <label for="sttng4"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                            id="sttng5"
                            name="sttng5"
                            type="checkbox"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            checked={row.emailCategoryList.otherEmails}/>
                        <label for="sttng5"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="icon-delete"></span>
                </td>

            </tr>
        )
    })

    return emailTemplate

}
handleChange(event){
 event.target.checked = false
 debugger;
}
```

How do I handle the checkbox check uncheck when my html is made dynamically based on conditions in React. Using state might be very cubersome because of multiple checkboxes any help?

Please help would be greatful

Comment: Use `state`. Using state with many items is not cumbersome. Cumbersome is your code now. It does not even use `id` correctly because it will repeat itself in every row.

Comment: Start by declaring the columns as an array, e.g. `const columns = [{label: 'Transactional Emails', name: 'transactionalEmails'}, ...]`. That should help you to remove the repetitive patterns from your code. The same is then valid for `state`. It's very easy to implement.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes I will add that it's a basic code will be removing that.

Answer (score 0):

Use state. While I am at it it would be a great idea to use Redux to store state. Regardless of how you keep the state, if you are woried about clutter, you could use dictionary for whole checkbox group where key would be id of checkbox.

While I am commenting your code have one common (but somewhat hard to figure out if you do not know about it) flaw. Your code to check or uncheck checkbox depending on state is something like this:

```
checked={row.emailCategoryList.crmEmails}
```

this will render all of your checkboxes as checked no matter if `row.emailCategoryList.crmEmails` evaluates to true or false. If you would like checkbox to be unchecked you have to omit checked attributte completely.